# Неправильно отображается текст

Tags: html

Добрый вечер!

Я работаю над [сайтом](http://sozvezdieudachi.com/) и недавно доделал главную страницу, дело в том, что в **Google Chrome**, **Mozila FireFox**, **Opera** и **Internet Explorer** страница отображается правильно:

[image]

А вот в **Яндекс-Браузере** и в **Maxthon**'е текст улетает, шрифты меняются так, как будто там нет никаких таблиц стилей.

Вопрос: можно ли как-то узнать, почему такое происходит, и исправить?

P.S. Я понимаю, что **Яндекс-Браузер** не самый хороший, но многие им пользуются, в т.ч. и посетители сайта.
P.P.S. Тэг **table** использовал, чтобы отцентрировать три элемента на линию (пока есть только центральный).
P.P.P.S. http://validator.w3.org/ говорит, что код правильный, кодировка тоже.

Comment: проблема воспроизводиться на разных машинах или только на Вашей (только Вашего друга)?

Comment: На всех машинах и только с этими браузерами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`font-family: "Cambria Math";` - это нестандартный шрифт.

Может, необходимо так:

```
font-family: "Cambria Math", serif;
```

`serif` - шрифты с засечками (антиквенные), типа Times;

`sans-serif` — рубленные шрифты (шрифты без засечек или гротески), типичный представитель — Arial;